# Does the yield spread between inflation-indexed bonds and regular bonds overestimate inflation expectations?

Tags: bonds, inflation, government-bonds, tips

Inflation expectations can be determined from the yield spread between [inflation-indexed bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation-indexed_bond) and non-inflation-indexed bonds. For example, US inflation expectations for the next 5 years can be determined from the yield spread between 5-year Treasury Inflation-Protected Securities (TIPS) and 5-year Treasury bonds (charts: [5-Year Breakeven Inflation Rate](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/T5YIE/)).

- Do people pay a premium for the inflation protection feature of inflation-indexed bonds?
- If so, wouldn't this lower the yield for inflation-indexed bonds, thus widening the yield spread between inflation-indexed bonds and non-inflation-indexed bonds?
- Does this mean that the yield spread consistently overestimates expected inflation?

Comment: Isn't accepting a much lower coupon already paying a premium?

Comment: How would you separate the value of the TIPS inflation adjustment to a buyer from the buyer's judgment of likely future inflation?  The buyer simply decides how much they're willing to pay for the security and the only information available to us is that price (or the implied yield.)

Comment: @BrianBorchers the idea is the buyer may be paying an insurance premium for the inflation protection above and beyond the expected inflation. Rather than buying a fixed rate above expected inflation, they derive additional value from having it actually linked to inflation.

Comment: My point is that there's no way to separate the two factors.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if actual inflation is less than expected inflation, then the buyer of a TIPS loses money compared with buying regular treasuries.  The inflation protection feature of TIPS can cut both ways.